# What is the fundamental problem of Kashmiri people with India?

Tags: india, pakistan, kashmir

Why do people of Kashmir want to separate from India?

What is the fundamental problem of Kashmiri people with India?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has you covered.

First, [Kashmir article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir) explains the history, with the main pertinent factor being that the population is majority Muslim (and therefore the problem is the same one that caused a division of the Raj into India and Pakistan in the first place).

Second, [Wikipedia on Kashmir conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_conflict) explains details:

> **India claims the entire state of Jammu and Kashmir, and, as of 2010, administers approximately 43% of the region**. It controls Jammu, the Kashmir Valley, Ladakh, and the Siachen Glacier. India's claims are contested by Pakistan, which administers approximately 37% of Kashmir, namely Azad Kashmir and Gilgit-Baltistan.[3][4] China currently administers Demchok district, the Shaksgam Valley, and the Aksai Chin region. China's claim over these territories has been disputed by India since China took Aksai Chin during the Sino-Indian War of 1962.[5]
>
> **The root of conflict between the Kashmiri insurgents and the Indian government is tied to a dispute over local autonomy**.[6] Democratic development was limited in Kashmir until the late 1970s, and by 1988, many of the democratic reforms introduced by the Indian Government had been reversed. Non-violent channels for expressing discontent were thereafter limited and caused a dramatic increase in support for insurgents advocating violent secession from India.[6] In 1987, a disputed state election[7] created a catalyst for the insurgency when it resulted in some of the state's legislative assembly members forming armed insurgent groups.[8][9][10] In July 1988 a series of demonstrations, strikes and attacks on the Indian Government began the Kashmir Insurgency.

Comment: This answer is based on an incorrect premise. I talked about Kashmiri people vs India, not Pakistan vs India.

Comment: This doesnt really say what the core of the problem is, just the actions involved in the escalation

Comment: @SoylentGray - "the population is majority Muslim". They want to be sovereign of non-Muslim India. It's not exactly a unique situation in the world.

Comment: That seems to be alot closer to the answer to the question than the facts you have posted here.

Comment: @SoylentGray - "that" was actually a quote from my answer :). The first paragraph.

Comment: That is not now I read your answer though.  The answer currently explains the escalation but does not explain why the problem existed or what the situation is now.  Unless you are trying to infer that the problem is just that they are majority muslim.  If so that seems rather xenophobic and ignores other issues.

Comment: @SoylentGray - mahjority Muslim in an area controlled by non-Muslims with nearby soveregity that is. How's that xenophobic? I very explicitly stated that: " therefore the problem is the same one that caused a division of the Raj into India and Pakistan in the first place"

Comment: But what is missing is why is that a problem...

Answer (score -1):

> What is the fundamental problem of Kashmiri people with India?

They want to either join Pakistan or want an independent country.

> Why do people of Kashmir want to separate from India?

1. 60% Kashmiris are Muslims but their Hindu king Hari Singh joined India without consulting his subjects.
2. Kashmiri Muslims are culturally separate from mainland India.
3. Indian army did gross Human rights violations in Kashmir to depopulate Muslims.
4. India never conducted any referendum according to UN resolution to give them a chance to decide for themselves.